# unixODBC 2.3.0 "_S_create_c_locale name not valid" error

Tags: locale, sles, odbc

I am attempting to setup HANA Smart Data Access on an SLES 11 sp3 environment.  For HANA to communicate with external data sources unixODBC 2.3.0 is used along with Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server 2012 (as I am attempting to connect to a MS SQL server db).  I have my odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini in my /etc directory and .odbc.ini in my home directory.  Based on all examples to date these appear to be configured correctly (at one point they were not and I received an appropriate error for them, this has been resolved.)

I am now receiving a new error, which is only returned when I attempt to connect to a datasource listed in my odbc.ini files:

"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
     what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Aborted"

So far my attempts to resolve this include altering the ssh_config file to prevent ssh sending my local environment variables, setting LC_ALL to en_US.UTF-8 and LANG=en_US, setting LC_ALL to c, and various combinations in between.  I have verified with locale -a that en_US.UTF-8, POSIX, and c are all installed.  I found a reference to an issue with boost here https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4688 however this is 5 years old and the impact is listed to sles 10, not 11.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it went away when I installed the en_US.UTF-8 locale.

ensure you have that installed on the machine where you are running unixodbc and sqlcmd

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/78224-install-the-ms-sql-odbc-driver-on-debian-7